# Matrix multiplication and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices. The rows of matrix $AB$ can be seen as the linear combinations of the rows of matrix $B$. Thus, if the determinant of a matrix is invariant to row operations, shouldn't $\det(AB) = \det(B)$?

I know it's $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$. Where is the fallacy in my argument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*if the determinant of a matrix is invariant under row operations...*"  No, that statement is incorrect.  A determinant *being zero vs nonzero* is invariant under row operations, however which nonzero value it is can be changed.

Comment: If you were to restrict yourself very heavily in terms of what operations you allow, you can have the determinant before and after stay the same... namely if you were to restrict yourself very specifically to replacing a row with that row unchanged plus a multiple of another row only.  Swapping rows (swaps sign of det), multiplying a row by a constant (multiplies det by that constant), or multiplying a row and then adding to a multiple of another row all can change the determinant.

Comment: How about $A = [1, 0; 2, 2]$ and $B = I$ giving simple addition of rows. Still the determinant of the product is not $detB = 1$

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, I think I got your point. The row operated upon has to be unchanged, is that it?

Comment: Yes. Row $i$ could be replaced by row $i$ (not a multiple of row $i$) plus any multiple of any *other* row without changing determinant. Using a multiple of row $i$ could and would change determinant however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\det(B)$ is a measurement of the "size" of (the rows of) $B$ in a certain sense. You are correct that $AB$ is a linear combination of rows of $B$, but linear combinations do not preserver size. For a slightly different example, consider the vectors $\{(1, 0), (0,1)\}$. They each have length $1$, but we certainly don't expect all linear combinations of them to have length $1$! For another example, $||\frac{1}{x^2+1}||_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $||\sin(x)/x||_2=\sqrt{\pi}$. But I can make $||a\frac{1}{x^2+1} + b\frac{\sin(x)}{x}||_2$ as large as I like by picking appropriate $a$ and $b$.

Typically, there are special types of linear transformations that do preserve size. In the case of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$, these are rotations. For the case of matrices, they are precisely multiplication by matrices of determinant $1$.